# How to get rid of bash control characters by evaluating them?

Tags: bash, control-characters

I have an output file (namely a log from `screen`) containing several control characters. Inside the screen, I have programs running that use control characters to refresh certain lines (examples would be `top` or anything printing progress bars).

I would like to output a `tail` of this file using PHP. If I simply read in that file and echo its contents (either using PHP functions or through calling `tail`, the output is messy and much more than these last lines as it also includes things that have been overwritten. If I instead run `tail` in the command line, it returns just what I want because the terminal evaluates the control characters.

So my question is: Is there a way to evaluate the control characters, getting the output that a terminal would show me, in a way that I could then use elsewhere (e.g., write to a file)?

Comment: The terminal is handling the control characters, not the shell. They don't have any meaning to a non-terminal. Does stripping them manually not do enough?

Comment: There may not be one pre-written and included in your distribution,  but it shouldn't be too difficult to write a filter that reads a file byte-by-byte and omits outputting the stuff that isn't wanted. All you would need is a list of the different characters/sequences you want to eliminate...

Comment: @twalberg: I think it's not really a matter of just eliminating them (PHP effectively does that by ignoring them). Say I ran a program printing its progress (0% done, 5% done, 10% done and so on, not writing new lines but rewriting that same line) then just stripping control characters will result in all these percentage values being in the output, whereas I only want the latest one to be there.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Thanks for the clarification, I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: You filter through something that understands terminal control characters. I'm not sure if any such things (other than terminals) exist though.

Comment: @Alex Well, that would involve a fair amount more than just filtering out the cursor motion and other control sequences. It would require essentially having a semantic understanding of what all the various sequences do as well. In other words a terminal, as suggested by @EtanReisner. Or maybe a clone of `screen` or `tmux`, but even those still rely on an underlying terminal to render things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@5gon12eder's answer got rid of some control characters (thanks for that!) but it did not handle the carriage return part that was even more important to me.

I figured out that I could just delete anything from the beginning of a line to the last carriage return inside that line and simply keep everything after that, so here is my sed command accomplishing that:

```
sed 's/^.*\r\([^\r]\+\)\r\?$/\1\r/g'
```

The output can then be further cleaned using @5gon12eder's answer:

```
cat screenlog.0 | sed 's/^.*\r\([^\r]\+\)\r\?$/\1\r/g' | sed 's,\x1B\[[0-9?;]*[a-zA-Z],,g'
```

Combined, this looks exactly like I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by “evaluating” the control characters but you could *remove* them easily.

Here is an example using `sed` but if you are already using PHP, its internal regex processing functionality seems more appropriate.  The command

```
$ sed 's,\x1B\[[0-9?;]*[a-zA-Z],,g' file.dat
```

will dump the contents of `file.dat` to standard output with all [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) removed.  (And I'm pretty sure that nothing else is removed except if your file contains invalid escape sequences in which case the operation is ill-defined anyway.)

Here is a little demo:

```
$ echo -e "This is\033[31m a \033[umessy \033[46mstring.\033[0m" > file.dat
$ cat file.dat
# The output of the above command is not shown to protect small children
# that might be browsing this site.
$ reset  # your terminal
$ sed 's,\x1B\[[0-9?;]*[a-zA-Z],,g' file.dat
This is a messy string.
```

The `less` program has some more advanced logic built in to selectively replace some escape sequences.  Read [the man page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/less1.html) for the relevant options.